# Evaluate datafield on boundfield to display text accordingly

Tags: asp.net, gridview, boundfield

Hello everyone How can I display different strings in boundfield according to value from datafield?

For instance, if datafield has a value of 1, it should display "Pending". If 2, "Deleted".

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't even know where to start.. :(

Comment: How about getting the 1 and 2 to render.

Comment: Are the columns autogenerated or not? Do you have control of the markup?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use server side function to display conditional value.

Take a look at this sample:

```
         <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-CssClass="TemplateFieldOneColumn">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label runat="server" Text='<% #GetLabelText(Eval("status")) %>' />
            </ItemTemplate>
         </asp:TemplateField>
```

Here is server side function declared on hosting page:

```
    public string GetLabelText(object dataItem)
    {
        string text = "";
        int? val = dataItem as int?;
        switch (val)
        {
            case 1:
                text = "Pending";
                break;
            case 2:
                text = "Deleted";
                break;

        }
        return text;
    }
```

Comment: @CM Kanode, Sorry for not choosing your answer. Turns out that this answer is more complete and it is exactly what I ended up using.

Comment: @HeinserDiaz, That's perfectly understandable.  It is a complete answer.  Part of my point was to get you to do some legwork on your own, instead of handing you all of the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use a TemplateField, and not a BoundField.  Then add an event to the GridView for RowDataBound.  In the method called, you'll evaluate your value (stored in a hidden field in the example below) and output the appropriate text (to Label in the example).

Here's a little bit of starter code.

```
<ItemTemplate>
  <asp:HiddenField ID="hdnStatus" runat="server" Value='<%# Bind("status") %>' />
  <asp:Label ID="lblStatus" runat="server" />
</ItemTemplate>
```

Use this, and do a little research on using the RowDataBound event.  If you get stuck, update your question with the code that you've written, and how you're stuck.  I'll be happy to help more.

Research is important, and it would be very beneficial for you to build up your skills in that area.  It's great to have someone to ask, but there are times when you only have yourself to rely upon.

Comment: You realy don't need HiddenField and Bind if you want a calculated value.

Answer (score 0):

For Boolean, You can do it like this:

```
<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Boolean.Parse(Eval("Status").ToString()) ? "Yes" : "No" %>'></asp:Label>
```

You can do for other type too.
Hope this will help you.