# If condition on a gridview for boundfield?

Tags: .net, vb.net, gridview, boundfield

I have a gridview with the following boundfiled. DataField is decimal value. If the value is anything higher than 0 I want to display as True in grdiview else false. How to do , if conditon for the boundfileld . can anyone help.  I can use TemplateField if that gives the solution.

```
<asp:BoundField HeaderText="fieldone" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left"
    DataField="Higher" NullDisplayText="0">
    <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Left"></HeaderStyle>
    <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Left"></ItemStyle>
</asp:BoundField>
<asp:BoundField HeaderText="fieldtwo" Rebate" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left"
    DataField="Lower" NullDisplayText="0">
    <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Left"></HeaderStyle>
    <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Left"></ItemStyle>
</asp:BoundField>
```

Comment: Any reason that you can't use template field? or can't you change data source before binding?

Comment: I can use template field.

Comment: [Evaluate datafield on boundfield to display text accordingly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13941184/evaluate-datafield-on-boundfield-to-display-text-accordingly)

Comment: @Damith: What is ItemStyle-CssClass="TemplateFieldOneColumn?

Comment: The following code should in ascx page or ascx.vb page? I use vb.net.public string GetLabelText(object dataItem)
    {
        string text = "";
        int? val = dataItem as int?;
        switch (val)
        {
            case 1:
                text = "Pending";
                break;
            case 2:
                text = "Deleted";
                break;

        }
        return text;
    }

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29251/discussion-between-damith-and-software)

Comment: I should have 20 reputation to talk here

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a templatefield & drop a label control inside it. Something like

```
<asp:TemplateField>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblStatus" runat="server" Text='<%# (Convert.ToDecimal(Eval("UnitPrice")) > 0) ? "True" : "False"   %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
```

Alternatively, you can also use `RowDataBound` event of gridview & use `FindControl` to apply the same.

Comment: when I use this code, In server page I get error " The '?" character cannot be used here."

Comment: @software That works for me. . You may be missing an enclosing quotation mark. Please ensure all server side code is enclosed properly inside single quotation marks'<%# your code goes here  %>'